# FastLink Update Site Flow results in blank iFrame

Tags: yodlee

I am able to follow the [FastLink Integration Guide](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/FastLink_for_Aggregation/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide) for the Add Site flow to successfully generate an "add site" page in an iFrame and link up a new site account.  However, when I follow the instructions for "update site", it results in a 200 response and a blank iFrame.  Here's an example URL I generated:

https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/prepareEditSiteAccounts.fastlinksb.action?access_type=oauthdeeplink&displayMode=desktop&oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b&oauth_nonce=Uz0DvzJdBJG&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1411681723&oauth_token=fdd266bda7e64c149e8f5e35bb0f1ee5&oauth_version=1.0&siteAccountId=10031675&oauth_signature=2Th/wXj2puTL2YzMxSfpFFw9gq8=

I am fairly certain that the signature is correct, because when I have had incorrect signatures the system has reliably returned an "invalid signature" error.

I am currently using the Sandbox.  Is this feature active in the Sandbox, and if so, any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Edit feature is not available at Sandbox environment and is only available once you have your own environment with Yodlee.

for more info on FastLink on sandbox please check my answer to your other question
[FastLink Refresh Site flow shows error page or goes directly to callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049062/fastlink-refresh-site-flow-shows-error-page-or-goes-directly-to-callback/26052130#26052130)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  This detail should be added to the documentation.