# FastLink Refresh Site flow shows error page or goes directly to callback

Tags: yodlee

When following the [documentation for the Refresh Site flow](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/FastLink_for_Aggregation/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide), I end up in one of two situations:

1) The iFrame shows this error screen:

[image]

this occurs with both real accounts and DAG accounts.

2) The iFrame is immediately redirected to my callback URL with `oauth_token`, `account_id` and `status` parameters, where `status` is "in_progress".  That's fine if that's how it's supposed to work, but it's my understanding based on the [FastLink Product Guide](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/FastLink_for_Aggregation/Yodlee_FastLink_Product_Guide) that the refresh flow should result in the iFrame showing something like this:

[image]

Here's an example URL I'm using to do the refresh site flow:

https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/refreshSiteAccount.fastlinksb.action?_flowId=siteRefresh&access_type=oauthdeeplink&displayMode=desktop&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1337%2Faccounts%2Fflcb&oauth_consumer_key=a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b&oauth_nonce=brHRw0pcm7H&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1411683203&oauth_token=efd25ae5021c4bd1a2464e82abad1415&oauth_version=1.0&siteAccountId=10031675&oauth_signature=VEuajIwPxUA43u1kdRIlICAulHc=

This is using the sandbox.  Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things about FastLink feature on developer portal -

1. Only linkAccount flow is enabled completely
2. Refresh flow will only work for non-MFA and siteAccounts which are in success state and doesn't have any [UAR](http://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes#UAR_Errors) errors.
3. Edit flow will not work on developer portal.

Refresh and Edit flow is available once you get your own environment with Yodlee.

Now about the error you are getting -

```
1) The iFrame shows this error screen:
```

An account can only be refreshed once in 15 minutes until in first attempt there was an [error](http://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes) . So if you have tried refreshing an account within 15 minutes of initial refresh , you will encounter this problem.

```
2) The iFrame is immediately redirected to my callback URL
```

If the account is non-MFA then this is how it will behave as there is no user interaction needed and hence UI is not shown. In case of MFA account you will get the UI.

> MFA stands for Multi factor authentication.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.  This should *really* be added to the documentation, considering that it actively encourages you to use the sandbox for testing but never mentions that most of the features won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will get this added in documentation soon.